# How to print the length of a string to the file

Tags: java

In this program I want to print the length of string in a external file but the problem is that it make the number of character in a string as a decimal value of character and prints the character which matches with the ascii value and print in a file.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
        class Fileoutputstream
        {
            public static void main(String args[])
            {
                try
                {
                    FileOutputStream foul=new FileOutputStream("/root/Documents/YG2108/DemoFiles.txt");
                    String s="hello Sir ";
                    String s1;
                    byte by[]=s.getBytes();
                    foul.write(by);
                    s1="Good Afternoon have a nice day frghunv9uhbzsmk zvidzknmbnuf ofbdbmkxm;jccipx nc     xdibnbnokcm knui9xkbmkl bv";
                    by=s.getBytes();
                    int yb=s.length();
                    int ascii = yb;     
                    foul.write(ascii);

                    System.out.println("Sucess");
                }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}     
            }
        }
```

Comment: do you have an actual question about this?

Comment: can you print the no of character in a string into a file

Comment: The answer to that is quite simple: "Yes", but I don't think that 'll help you much further at this point

Comment: you make print the code and  I will understand that automatically.

Comment: don't ask other people to do your work for you. Try for yourself, and once you have concrete questions and can explain where you are stuck, post that information here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to write length() of string s1 in DemoFiles.txt

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    class Fileoutputstream
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            try
            {

         File file=new File("C:\\Users\\1201567\\Desktop\\test.txt");

         BufferedWriter bf=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

         String s1="Good Afternoon have a nice day frghunv9uhbzsmk zvidzknmbnuf ofbdbmkxm;jccipx nc     xdibnbnokcm knui9xkbmkl bv";

         int length=s1.length();

         bf.write(String.valueOf(length));
         bf.flush();
         System.out.println("Sucess");
     }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}     
        }
    }
```