# problem in printing the content from the file

Tags: java, file-io

I am writing the length of the string into a file and the result is that value is being considered as ASCII value and the character specified with ASCII value is written in the file and then I try to read that character from with the help of FileInputStream and BufferInputStream and the result will not be displayed on the console. Why is the character from the file not printed to the console?

```
import java.io.*;
class Fileoutput{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {

         File f=new File("C:\\Users\\parsh\\YG2108\\Testfile.txt");
         FileInputStream fins=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\parsh\\YG2108\\Testfile.txt");
         FileOutputStream fouts=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\parsh\\YG2108\\Testfile.txt");
         FileWriter bf=new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\parsh\\YG2108\\Testfile.txt");
         BufferedInputStream fin=new BufferedInputStream(fins);
         BufferedOutputStream fout=new BufferedOutputStream(fouts);
         BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(bf);
         int i;
         String s1="Good Afternoon have a nice day frghunv9uhbzsmk zvidzknmbnuf ofbdbmkxm;jccipx nc     xdibnbnokcm knui9xkbmkl bv";

         int length=s1.length();           //findin string length
         System.out.println(length);       //printing length on console
         fout.write(length);               //writting into the file
         System.out.println("Sucess");
         while((i=fin.read())!=-1)
         {    
             System.out.print((char)i);    
         }    
         bw.close();
         fout.close();
         fin.close();
         bf.close();
         fouts.close();
         fins.close();
         System.out.println("All done");
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}     
    }
}
```

Comment: already answered @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183123/how-to-print-the-length-of-a-string-to-the-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the length of a string to the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183123/how-to-print-the-length-of-a-string-to-the-file)

Comment: @Tarun Firstly understand the problem what I am trying to say ,this is not the same problem

Comment: @Yogesh "*I am writing the length of the string into a file and the result is that value is being considered as ASCII value and the character specified with ASCII value is written in the file*" is same as your previous problem

Comment: duplicate... should be put on hold or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

First See If The problem Is In The Way you Write inTo the File
Follow This Link  [How To Read From A File In Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-reading-text-file-java/)       and See This Link Also [How to Write Into A File in Java](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/)  
Problem Is not in The Asci Because if the Length of the String is int (As it should be )
You Should Parse it using Integer.tostring(length_of_the_string)  before you write it into the File

instead of this line

```
fout.write(length);
```

write this line

```
fout.write(Integer.toString(length));
```

You can Google for your Problem Before Asking on Stackoverflow ( It Might be Solved Before On Stackoverflow )

Comment: Sir, I don't have any issue regarding the  length is considering as ASCII value but the problem is the read() method is not working to print on console and this is not solved on make search on google

Comment: @Yogesh Check the Answer Now

Comment: Sir, see the previous comment what I said about my problem in the program

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mixing reading with writing - you have both reading objects and writing objects opened at the same time. Since you are using `BufferedOutputStream` output is not written directly to file (when buffer is not full) and you are reading file before it contains any data.

So to solve it, flush the output stream with `fout.flush();` before reading, or ideally separate reading from writing:

```
import java.io.*;

class Fileoutput {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        File f = new File("test.txt");
        f.createNewFile();
        try (FileOutputStream fouts = new FileOutputStream(f); BufferedOutputStream fout = new BufferedOutputStream(fouts);) {
            String s1 = "Good Afternoon have a nice day frghunv9uhbzsmk zvidzknmbnuf ofbdbmkxm;jccipx nc     xdibnbnokcm knui9xkbmkl bv";

            int length = s1.length();
            System.out.println(length);
            fout.write(length);
            //fout.flush(); //optional, everything is flushed when fout is closed
            System.out.println("Sucess");
        }
        try (FileInputStream fins = new FileInputStream(f); BufferedInputStream fin = new BufferedInputStream(fins);) {
            int i;
            while ((i = fin.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) i);
            }
            System.out.println("All done");
        }
    }
}
```